# asp codebehind for button as backspace of keyboard

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a button and I want it to serve as **backspace** button of my keyboard. So that it should send me to the previous page of application; here is my code:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Button1.Text = Button1.Text.Remove(Button1.Text.Length - 1, 1);
 }
```

It is not working. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but I don't think the navigate to previous page works like that.

You could emulate that behaviour using something like

```
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this.  Here is a server side and client side way of doing it.

**Server side**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strBack = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    Response.Redirect(strBack);
}
```

**Client side**

```
<asp:button id="btnBack" runat="server" text="Back" OnClientClick="JavaScript: window.history.back(1); return false;"></asp:button>
```

Comment: yes it worked for my, another way i found to solve this issue is: '
<a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Go Back to Previous Page</a>' using link button